# Wordpress Footer weird behavior

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I have a contact form in the second footer area (Gravity Forms) and the height of the textarea must be 40px to fit in the input div. However if i type 5 or 6 of random rows and select the text while moving the mouse down THE WHOLE FOOTER SLIDES UP!! It drives me nuts i tried lots of ways but none worked.

Check it out and test it yourself. Go to the contact form in the footer and fill it out with 5 or 6 rows. Then select some the text and slowly move the mouse down. It seems that this problem is not happening in Firefox (using Chrome) or if the height of the textarea is above 80px.

http://amplifiedvideodesign.com/

What can i do to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: seems like a typical reverse gravity issue to me